# Decoding unicode charactors recieving from android and ios emojis with javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji

I have a web application that recieves messages from ios and android apps. Messages can contain emoji. In our web application stores them as unicodes. So I am trying to create a web page that displays user entered emojis. Sample emoji unicodes recieve from IOS app like \ud83d\ude1f

I tried jquery-emojiarea library. But it doesen't convert the unicode like above to emojis. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: If the user has a unicode font with the emoji characters, **and** the browser can find them, you need do nothing. Otherwise try a using a web downloadable emoji font in the page. On my system, a javascript string of `"\ud83d\ude1f"` displays as  (a sad face, not some unknown character symbol).

Answer (score 0):

For emoji you have to replace each unicode with an image...you can do manually...See this http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html or try to resolve that with a library....